# Swift Autolayout doesn't work in Xcode 9.3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, autolayout

Here I have two label to show in Xcode.
If I do not add any constraint,  it seems well.

**without constraint**

[image: without constraint]

**shown in simulator**

[image: shown in simulator]

Then I need autolayout so that it could show normal in different devices. But once I add constraints, they move all my labels to the left board. No matter how I set it, it doesn't work.

For example, once I set a constant leading space to border,

**only one constraint, leading space to content, value 15**

[image: only one constraint, leading space to content, value 15],

my label jumped to the border.

**jump to border. The same thing happened to textfield**

[image: jump to border. The same thing happened to textfield]

This confusing me for nearly three days. How could I make it work?

UPDATE:

I tried to add possible constrains, the constraint lines shown blue, but once I ran it, the label and textfield covered each other. I don't know if there are some important things I still lost?

[For label, I added a leading space constraint, and center vertically constraint. For textfield, I added a leading space to label, and vertical center constraint. When I ran it, they coverd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8aPRO.png)

[textfield covered label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JqZCm.png)

Comment: What height are you returning for the cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have no constraints, iOS uses something known at the autoresizing mask to create constraints for you at runtime, locking your views in place wherever they were in Interface Builder. These constraints won't work well for different content sizes or different devices, so you should always fully constrain your UI.

When you added the single constraint, Interface Builder told you that your interface wasn't properly constrained (the red arrow next to your view controller) and would give you guidance if you looked at that content. However, running the app with only a single constraint on that label meant that the system didn't apply the autoresizing mask like normal and the layout system essentially just set all of the other values to zero at runtime. This includes the `height` and `width` of the label, as well as its `x` and `y` position. With zeros for all of those values, what you're seeing here is the content of your label being rendered at `0,0`, with a label that has 0 height and width. However, with `clipsToBounds` defaulted to `false`, the label's content is still visible, and so is shown as you see.

tl;dr: You need to constrain your entire UI, as Interface Builder was trying to tell you.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. Actually, I had tried. But it still not worked well. I have updated the question, the picture shown the running results. Do you have some hints about if I still miss some important points?

Comment: You need to add constraints until Interface Builder stops giving you the error indicator. It should tell which constraints it doesn't have, like height or width.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time. I would try to track Interface.

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide the position `x` and `y` of the label by using constraints. In this case, you have the `x` value but no value for the `y`. For example: if you want to center the label in the cell, you can select the label, then press the `Align` button in the right-bottom of the storyboard and select `Vertically in Container`.

Comment: Thanks very much for your comment. I had tried this. But it doesn't work well. I have updated the question, the picture shown in it. I still wonder but I am not sure I lost some settings in this project. Do you have any other comments? Thanks very much for your time.

Answer (score 0):

In general for each element in view you need 4 constrains. Width, height, x and y. Some elements need only x and y, like labels, switch, ... but some others need all 4. In your case you need to define x and y for your label.

I would suggest to watch this YouTube tutorial so you will have a better understanding of auto-layout in X-Code:

https://youtu.be/izES1zQjRUU

Comment: Thanks a lot for your advice. I would check this.